# In Bigtable, what is the highest valid value for a custom timestamp?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I am using the HBase java driver v1.16 and I am experiencing a weird behaviour when creating a cell with custom timestamp as a `long` with a value above 2^53?

Is there a limit on the value of a custom timestamp?
Does it depend of the client driver language and version or is it inherent to Bigtable?

Edit: I encountered the same limitation with `cbt`.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are using the HBase java driver v1.16 and you are experiencing weird behaviour when creating a cell with a custom timestamp as a `long` with a value above 2^53 in Bigtable. You have also asked for the limit (highest value) and dependency of the custom timestamp, which is causing this discrepancy.

The largest HBase timestamp that Bigtable can store is Long.MAX_VALUE/1000, any value larger than that is converted to Long.MAX_VALUE/1000. As a result, large reversed timestamp values might not convert correctly, this could be a reason for experiencing weird behaviour with values more than 2^53.

Bigtable stores timestamps in microseconds, while HBase stores timestamps in milliseconds. This distinction has implications when the HBase client library is used for Bigtable and has data with reversed timestamps. This could help resolve the dependency between the two.

Since you are accessing Cloud Bigtable using a customized version of the Apache HBase client for Java, therefore, when timestamp value is entered in milliseconds in HBase it converts into microseconds as it is inherent to bigtable, because it stores timestamps in microseconds. The client library converts between microseconds and milliseconds because of this distinction with the two.

You can refer to this link for more information on the above mentioned points.
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-differences

You can refer to this documentation for more information on HBase class TimeRange.
https://hbase.apache.org/1.1/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/TimeRange.html

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
Two questions:

1. Why does the limitation happens with `cbt` then?
2. Does the limitation also happens with Bigtable java driver?

Comment: Please refer to the second answer for your queries on cbt and java driver @viebel

Answer (score 0):

According to the API reference documentation for Go language, it has a type [Timestamp](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#Timestamp) which says type Timestamp is int64. Timestamp is in units of microseconds since 1 January 1970. **However timestamp will be truncated to millisecond granularity because this is currently the only granularity supported by Go Client Library**. So that explains why cbt  is facing the same issue as HBase java driver when timestamp values greater than 2*53 are entered in cells.

Looking at Java Client for bigtable, the granularity is set to millis only as in the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/admin/rpc/google.bigtable.admin.v2#google.bigtable.admin.v2.Table.TimestampGranularity)

**The Hbase Client for Java, Java client for Bigtable and cbt all support a timestamp granularity upto milliseconds.**
Though Bigtable stores timestamps in microseconds internally,it supports setting cell timestamps to millis granularity.

Both TIMESTAMP_GRANULARITY_UNSPECIFIED and MILLIS have the same effect. Creating cells with higher granularity than the supported value is rejected by the server.
Keeping timestamp values with precision of about milliseconds can help in resolving the weird behaviour in your bigtable cell instance.